# Python Regex replace but only if two or more characters precede regex expression

Tags: python, regex

I have a pattern: `"two_or_more_characters - zero_or_more_characters"` and I want to replace it with `"two_or_more_characters"`, where `"-"` is a dash.

I created regex for it:

```
re.sub(r'-[\w(){}\[\],.?! ]+', '', t)
```

and it works as expected for some cases. For example for `t = "red-fox"` we will get `red`. But it does not work as needed for example: `t = "r-fox"`. The result is `r` but I am looking for way to keep `r-fox` instead.

If text has more then one dash then we need to remove text only after last dash. For example for `t = "r-fox-dog"` the result should be `r-fox`

Comment: 'r ' is 'r' <space>, which IS 2 or more characters, so in my opinion the replacement is correct here. Perhaps, give us a better explanation of what you want. Do you want to ignore spaces before dash?

Comment: What if your text has more dashes? Like "todo-nodo-undo"?

Comment: @PetrBlahos I edited the body of Q to address your questions Thanks.

Comment: @zvone: True enough, I would recommend using rpartition though. But regex will automatically solve the "at least 2 characters" task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a backref - that's the thing in the () in the regular expression,
and \1 to "paste" it.
I think this works well enough:

```
re.sub(r'(.{2,})-.*', r'\1', "ss-fox")
```